# How to replace a null or empty value in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a function pulling data from an appliance, here is the code:

```
$allSFD = get-sklqsessions -apil $userAdmin $passAdmin $applianceIP  <- so far there is no issue here
```

now :

```
   if ($allSFD)
        {
    <#$allSFD | select-object @{N='username'; E={$_.username}},
                               @{N='Client IP'; E={$_.publicip}}, | format-table -autosize 
    #>
    
    ### write files
    
    $allSFD | export-Clixml -path "c:\users\temp\file1.xml"

}

else { write-warning "no users connected to the appliance"}
```

whenever there is a user connected to the system, but idle, the appliance will keep the users in the connected list but his/her ip will be empty no IP, so no data in client ip = publicip.
Then I want to add something like `0.0.0.0`

Right now any idle user is getting exported to the xml just a user name no ip , the publicip is empty.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put anything you like into a property expression, including control statements like `if(){...}`:

```
$allSFD |Select Username,@{N='Client IP'; E={if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.publicip)){"0.0.0.0"}else{$_.publicip}}} |Export-CliXml ...
```

---

Single-line if/else statements might look a bit "messy", but as [@mklement0 helpfully points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495269/how-to-replace-a-null-or-empty-value-in-powershell#comment117552769_66495338), in PowerShell 7+ we have a ternary statement that we can use instead:

```
$allSFD |Select Username,@{N='Client IP'; E={[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.publicip) ? "0.0.0.0" : $_.publicip }} |Export-CliXml ...
```

This makes it slightly more readable :)

Comment: Nice. Just to give the PowerShell (Core) v7+ features more exposure: there you can simplify to `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.publicip) ? '0.0.0.0' : $_.publicip` or, if `$_.publicip` is only ever `$null` (rather than `''`) when not set: `$_.publicip ?? '0.0.0.0'`